# ASP.Net MVC Area not picking registered types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working on an ASP.Net application with a couple of `MVC Areas` defined. When I try to use dependency injection on a controller within an `Area`, I am getting the error below.

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

I am using a Unity Container, and it appears the registered dependencies are not making it to the `MVC Area`.

Setup is pretty typical in the `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(MyConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Are there an additional steps I am missing in order to inject dependencies in an MVC Area controller?

### Additional Information

Here is the Area registration class:

```
public class MyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "MyArea";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "MyArea_default",
                "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Unity Container:

```
     public static class MyConfig{

     public static IUnityContainer dependencyResolver { get; set; }

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Create Unity container
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // Register service types
            container.RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeService>();
            // omitted for brevity

            // Create unity resolver
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            dependencyResolver = container;
}
```

Area Controller:

```
private ISomeServce SomeServce;

public LabController(ISomeServce someServce)
{
  SomeServce = someServce;
}
```

Comment: what about unity config file? The reason of the error is incorrect dependency injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API and MVC are two entirely different things. Your question originally stated you are using MVC, but your DI configurtion is only for Web API.

### Configuration for MVC (and Areas)

As per the [Dependency Injection Tutorial on MSDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection), you are missing an important piece of your DI setup - namely, your `Application_Start` method is not setting up MVC to use DI. It is only set up to configure DI for Web API.

You need to either implement (or find an implementation based on) `IControllerFactory` or `IDependencyResolver` and set it at application startup in order to inject the controller dependencies.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory(container));

// Or...

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: Would this be within the `MVC Area`? Injecting controller dependencies are working as expected in the root of the application, but not the `MVC Area`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Could you post both your area configuration and how you are starting your DI container (seems to be missing from `Application_Start`). And also post the controller in question.

Comment: @MikeHenderson - I updated my answer, but basically it is the same. You have not setup the DI config for MVC, you have only set it up for Web API.

Comment: You're correct The project was setup for Web API only. The resolution was a little different since this project is using Unity, but you nailed the overall problem.